# R programming mean

Tags: r, mean

Hi i am very new to R and have ran in to a big issue.
the data im working with is way bigger but making it small to explain easier.
here is my data example.

Data.file is named: data1

```
1. Product  price
2.   egd    132   
3.   egd    195
4.   apd    185
5.   apd    132
6.   xys    153
```

So first i wanted to know how get the top 10 most used products and did the command: `sort(table(data1$product),decreasing=TRUE)[1:10]`
and that worked perfectly!

Now i want to get the average price(i think its called the mean?) from each product of the top 10 products, something like this:

```
1. EGD  APD 
2. 132  321  
and so on...
```

and after that i want the same but for all products except the top 10.

Is this possible? and if so i would be very grateful for help!

Best regards,
Surken

Answer (score 2):

First convert product into a factor column:

```
test <- data.frame(product=c('egd', 'egd', 'apd', 'apd', 'xys'),
    price=c(132, 195, 185, 132, 153))

test$product <- factor(test$product)

  product price
1     egd   132
2     egd   195
3     apd   185
4     apd   132
5     xys   153
```

Then use tapply to calculate the mean for each factor:

```
tapply(test$price, test$product, mean)

apd   egd   xys 
158.5 163.5 153.0
```

You can then sort that vector in the same way as before using `sort` with `decreasing=T` and index the first ten `[1:10]` and everything else `[11:length(results)]`

Comment: The only issue here is that i have like 30000 product lines and all of them have a price, so it will be hard to add them all manually :/

Comment: So do you have a file you need to read in?  I suggest looking at the `?read.table` documentation on reading files into R first.

Comment: i have an excel file that i saved as .CSV, that i have added, and i have removed all NA.

Comment: and managed to get get top 10 products from it. i can also calculate the average price for an individual product but since its so many products it will take forever.

Comment: `data <- read.csv('path/to/file/data1.csv')` should get it into R, then follow the above answer.  If you have more questions on reading files, google has plenty of examples.

Comment: The information has been added properly and everything, it is what to type to get what i need calculated that is the issue :/

Comment: data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=';')    is what i used. because they were separated by ;